# How to customize the icon of muidropdown

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
    <FormControl variant="filled" sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-filled-label">Age</InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
      id="demo-simple-select-filled"
      value={age}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      <MenuItem value="">
        <em>None</em>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={10}>One </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={20}>Two</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={30}>Threee</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

I want to replace the dropdown caret icon with a different one. How can we customize it in MuiSelect component[image: This is the existing icon]

[image: This is the icon I wanted]

Answer (score 0):

Well according to [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/) you would use the `IconComponent` prop.

Answer (score 0):

In the Select you can add the

```
IconComponent={KeyboardArrowDownIcon}
```

or if you need to use a custom icon or add further customisations you can render it like this

```
IconComponent={() => <KeyboardArrowDownIcon sx={{color: 'blue'}}/>}
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-demo-material-ui-forked-r5snug?file=/demo.tsx:985-1052) to play with